# multi state or multistate or multi-state

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, terminology

I am not sure if this question belongs to English language StackExchange.

In the context of multiconfigurational methods, what is the correct way to write multi-state character:

1. multi-state character
2. multistate character
3. multi state character

Personally I would go with option 1.

Comment: I don't think it changes the meaning, i.e. doesn't really matter.

Comment: Of course, but there is still something called orthography. If there is one correct solution I want to use it. Wif jur argument ai kud justify eni riting. ;)

Comment: @mcocdawc - I prefer option (1), and cite Donald Knuth's reasoning as given [here](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/email.html). However, Knuth suggests that the hyphenated versions of "newly coined" words morph to unhyphenated versions (e-mail becomes email, for example) as they gain acceptance and are more frequently used, which indicates to me that option (2) is not off the table, certainly because the word is not newly coined. I would argue that wide acceptance and usage of the wording in the context given here is not demonstrated, however, and fall back to option (1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's rather about language then chemistry.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt thank you very much for this answer. If you write it as "real" answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: @mcocdawc - I would happily do so, will vote to reopen. Ultimately the community will decide. You might want to make it more chemistry focused or include wording to overcome the issues relating to its closure.

Comment: While I think this is as much a chemistry question as it is a language question, and I think it is better answered here, I am a little bit reluctant to overrule community decision. || On the matter at hand: 1 and 2 are correct and common spellings. Which one you choose is up to you basically, but be consistent. So if you write [multiconfigurational](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiconfiguration) (as you did), you should write multistate, multireference, etc.. If you prefer the hyphenated versions (I'd choose them), you should use them for all.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Q is reopened.

Comment: My rule of thumb: Leeloo Dallas had `Multi Pass`, so all other arguments are invalid:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer option (1), and cite Donald Knuth's reasoning as given [here](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/email.html).

Knuth asserts that hyphenated versions of "newly coined" words morph to unhyphenated versions (e-mail becomes email, for example) as they gain acceptance and are more frequently used, which indicates to me that option (2) is not off the table, certainly because the word is not newly coined.

However, I argue that wide acceptance and usage of the wording in the context given here is *not* demonstrated and fall back to option (1). Finally, as pointed out by Martin in the comment thread, be consistent and use (or don't use) hyphenation regardless of which variation you choose.